# Compare two imported text file

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, import

Hey guys just wanted to see if what I'm thinking will work, I am in my second semester of learning java. 
Here's the directions for a hw assignment:
Design a class that checks if the contents of two text files are identical and, if not, determines how many lines are different. Lines are different if they differ in one or more characters. 
So, I'm thinking that I should read in the texts line by line, convert each line to a string and then store each line in a spot in an array.Once I have done this I will have to arrays. Then, I plan on going through each array and comparing them. 
Is my thinking on this problem correct?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class myfilereader
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.io.IOException
    {
        ArrayList<String> Diff = new ArrayList<String>();
        Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("/Users/Home/Desktop/File2.txt"));
        ArrayList<String> ArrayList1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        while (s.hasNext())
        {
            ArrayList1.add(s.next());
        }
        s.close();

        Scanner s1 = new Scanner(new File("/Users/Home/Desktop/File1.txt"));
        ArrayList<String> ArrayList2 = new ArrayList<String>();
        while (s.hasNext())
        {
            ArrayList2.add(s1.next());
        }
        s1.close();
        HashSet hs = new HashSet();
        for(String i : ArrayList1) hs.add(i);
        for(String i : ArrayList2)
        {
            if(!hs.add(i))
                Diff.add(i);
        }

        String result = "+";
        for (int i = 0; i < Diff.size(); i++)
        {   
            result += " " + Diff.get(i);
        }
        System.out.println(result);

    }
}
```

Here are the exact errors I'm getting"

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Scanner closed
    at java.util.Scanner.ensureOpen(Scanner.java:1046)
    at java.util.Scanner.hasNext(Scanner.java:1310)
    at myfilereader.main(myfilereader.java:19)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use that: [Apache Commons Collections](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/download_collections.cgi)
Then you load two files into ArrayList and use one of the Collections method

Comment: Can't use any add-ons :0 I'll try to post some examples of trying it out tomorrow! Or later today i guess xD

Comment: Just load files into arrayList
Have two nested loops
First for one Array second for another
and compare first element of array1 to all elements of array2 as long as all elements of array1 are checked against array2 elements

Comment: Okay, here's what I have so far, but I'm getting a few errors. At the end of this code, I am just trying to print out the differences between the two ArrayLists. I'll update what I have in the question.